# How can I sniff the traffic performed by Flash files?

Tags: flash, http, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I was the "inspect" the browser open while doing file uploads on the site "uploaded" then I noticed that the file is uploaded and made by flash and does not appear traffic tool tool "inspect" (I was in Chrome) I tried Firefox and Firebug also does not show anything either.

You can see this traffic somehow, I tested some other programs but not succeeded as well.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Flash is an seperate process run in the browser, so you would probobly need to use an Network Analyzer like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or any other software that can capture network adapter traffic, Unless the traffic is encrypted it should not be readable.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), and I find it to be one of the best tools to monitor network traffic. Download it and give it a try, should solve your problem. Hope this helps.